# Angular Meteor: MongoDB collections are not shown in the UI

Tags: angular-meteor

I'm trying to use angular-meteor with Meteor and following the tutorial from https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/angular/collections

I have the below code files:

**index.html**

```html
<body ng-app="web-alerts">
  <div ng-include="'client/index.ng.html'"></div>
</body>
```

**client/index.ng.html**

```
<div ng-controller="AlertsListCtrl">
    <h1>Tasks:</h1>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="webAlert in tasks">
            <b>{{webAlert.title}}</b>
            <p>Url: {{webAlert.url}}</p>
            <p>Emails: {{webAlert.emails}}</p>
            <p>Keywords: {{webAlert.keywords}}</p>
            <p>Frequency: {{webAlert.frequency}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**client/app.js**

```js
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");


if (Meteor.isClient) {
  angular.module('web-alerts', ['angular-meteor']);

  angular.module('web-alerts').controller('AlertsListCtrl', ['$scope', '$meteor',
    function($scope, $meteor) {
      $scope.tasks = $meteor.collection(Tasks);
    }
  ]);
}
```

In MongoDB, I have added some items to the collection.

> meteor:PRIMARY> db.tasks.find()
>
> { "_id" : ObjectId("55fe7cbc330d5b4cfb52ed9e"), "title" : "aaa
>   yyy zzzz", "description" : "desc goes here",
>   "url" : "http://abcd.com", "keywords" : "abcd, efgh,
>   ijkl", "emails" : "",
>   "frequency" : 10 }

But I don't see the collection data in the UI. If I assign a static array to $scope.tasks in controller, it works fine.

What could be the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by moving client/app.js to the root folder.

Can someone explain what could be the problem?

Comment: When you have it in client folder, try removing the test for isClient